# ssh: Could not resolve hostname username: no address associated with name, git

Tags: git, ssh

In my shared host directory I have a flask app in a git directory:

```
username@so6 [~/domains/mi]# ls -la
total 88
drwxr-xr-x  7 username username 4096 Jun 28 12:30 ./
drwxr-xr-x 19 username username 4096 Jun 28 12:30 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 username username   59 Jun 28 12:30 .bowerrc
drwxrwxr-x  5 username username 4096 Jun 28 12:30 .git/
-rw-rw-r--  1 username username  400 Jun 28 12:30 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x  3 username username 4096 Jun 28 12:30 .idea/
-rw-rw-r--  1 username username 8192 Jun 28 12:30 dev.db
-rw-rw-r--  1 username username 2528 Jun 28 12:30 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x  3 username username 4096 Jun 28 12:30 migrations/
drwxrwxr-x  8 username username 4096 Jun 28 12:30 myflaskapp/
```

I want to merge this with a local copy so I tried:

```
$ git remote add shared ssh://username:password@mydomain.net/home/username/domains/mi.git
~/mi (master)
$ git pull shared master
ssh: Could not resolve hostname username: no address associated with name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how the `git` uri looks like:

```
ssh://username:password@mydomain.net/home/username/domains/mi.git
```

You can't put `ssh` passwords in the `uri`. Also the separator between the hostname and path is `:` and not `/`. It should be just

```
ssh://username@mydomain.net:/home/username/domains/mi.git
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to include the password in the url?

Comment: No. It is not a good idea nor secure way. But you can use public key authentication without password.